# How to store Firefox extension icon state locally

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I have a firefox extension that can change the extension icon in the html options menu when you click on the icon image.

options.html

```
<body>
    <section class="browser-icons">
      <img id="black-trash" img src="../icons/black_trash.png" title="Black trash"/>
      <img id="red-trash" img src="../icons/red_trash.png" title="Red trash"/>
    </section>
```

options.js

```
const blackTrash = document.getElementById("black-trash"); 
const redTrash = document.getElementById("red-trash");
    
function setBlack() {
  browser.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../icons/black_trash.png"});
}
function setRed() {
  browser.browserAction.setIcon({path: "../icons/red_trash.png"});
}
    
blackTrash.addEventListener("click", setBlack);
redTrash.addEventListener("click", setRed);
```

However, if you change the icon to red, it resets to black (default) whenever you restart your browser.

How do I save the icon state locally?

Comment: You need to add storage to make it persistent. Try to save it to a `localStorage` then retrieve it when you reload the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

I don't know exacly but try the localStorage to this -

```
function setBlack() {
  browser.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../icons/black_trash.png"});
  localStorage.setItem('icon', '../icons/black_trash.png');
}
```

To call this you will need only `localStorage.getItem('icon');`

I don't know if this solve your problem but we are here to learn too ;)

Comment: Thanks! This implementation works well. Do you know if there is a way to get current icon file state before locally storing it?

Comment: I recommend you to use the icons by cdn like storing your icons in upload site services because it reflects directly in the persistence of your application.